# How to run boto3 run job flow in a dry run

Tags: python, boto3, amazon-emr

I have multiple EMR jobs that are created using `boto3's` `run_job_flow()` function and basically I want to test if the configurations passed to this function are correct, without actually creating the clusters and incurring costs. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest that you use [mocking with `moto`](https://github.com/spulec/moto). See, e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56994904/how-to-mock-aws-calls-when-using-boto3-version-1-8-or-higher-with-moto) to see how it can be done. You can also [review what StackOverflow has on `moto`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/moto)

Answer (score 1):

Moto would be your best bet but be careful because moto and boto3 have incompatibilities when you use boto3 at or above version 1.8. It is still possible to work around the problem using moto's stand-alone servers but you cannot mock as directly as the moto documentation states. Take a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56994904/how-to-mock-aws-calls-when-using-boto3-version-1-8-or-higher-with-moto) if you need more details.